# heroImage field not showing up in GraphiQL

Tags: contentful

In GraphiQL I am trying to query the heroImage field from a Contentful blog post, which exists by default within my Blog Post content type:

[image]

Raw query code:

```
{
    allContentfulBlogPost {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
          body {
             childMarkdownRemark {
                excerpt
            }
          }
          heroImage {
             gatsbyImageData(
             layout: CONSTRAINED
             placeholder:BLURRED
             width: 300
            )
          }
        }
      } 
    }
  }
```

But I am getting the error: **"Cannot query field "heroImage" on type "ContentfulBlogPost".",**

In fact, the heroImage field isn't even showing up on my GraphiQL explorer (see pic below), and I cannot figure out why. The field does indeed exist, and I have even made sure that each blog post has a hero image associated with it.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am quite stumped with this one.

Comment: Silly question: is your `heroImage` published?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the data is published, all the way to the top level. If it is an image on a blog, ensure both the image and the parent blog entry is published.
2. Ensure that at least one "heroImage" field has a file stored against it
3. You can't query the image directly in the graphQL explorer. Your best bet is to go for the "url" property, once it shows up.
4. Restart / re-query the contentful end point by re-running gatsby develop.
5. If something gets stuck, run gatsby clean, then gatsby develop.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same exact problem. I ran the command
'npm install gatsby-transformer-remark' and re-ran gatsby develop. Now heroImage is showing up

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Running gatsby clean worked for me